# php script running out of memory when large amounts of data being written to file in batches

Tags: php, batch-processing, fwrite

I am having continuous problems with my script running our of memory.

I need the script to loop through each customer in a database and then to get all the product data and geneate a text file.  Each customer can have anything between 1 and 100,000 products.

I bring out the product data in batches of 1,000 and write to a file to try and stop the script from timing out.  This has improved a great deal, however, I am still having issues with customers what have large numbers of products.  It seems to have issues with customers that have over 5,000 products.

It seems to stop writing to file after the 5th batch (5,000 prods) but the browser just hangs as though it is still generating the file but the product no in the file never increase.

Can anyone help?

```
set_time_limit(0);

$db = new msSqlConnect('db');

$select = "SELECT customer FROM feeds ";

$run = mssql_query($select);

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($run)){
    $arg = $row['customer'];
    $txt_file = 'shopkeeper/'. $arg . '.txt';   
    $generated = generateFeed($db, $arg, $txt_file);

    if ($generated){
        $update = "UPDATE feeds SET lastGenerated = '$generated' WHERE customer = '$arg' ";
        mssql_query($update);
    }

}

function generateFeed($db, $customer, $file){
    //if file already exists then delete file so can write new file
    if (file_exists($file)){
        unlink($file);
    }   

    $datafeed_separator = "|";

    //get product details       
    $productsObj = new Products($db, customer)

    //find out how many products customer has
    $countProds = $productsObj->countProducts();

    $productBatchLimit = 1000;          

        //create new file
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');

    $counter = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $countProds; $i += $productBatchLimit) {

        $txt = '';

        $limit = $productBatchLimit*$counter;

        $products = $productsObj->getProducts($i, $limit);      

            foreach($products as $product){

                    $txt .=   
                    $prod_name . $datafeed_separator . 
                    $prod_brand . $datafeed_separator . 
                    $prod_desc . $datafeed_separator .
                    $prod_price . $datafeed_separator . "\n";   
                }
            }   

        fwrite($fh, $txt);
        flush();
        $counter++;     
    }
    fclose($fh);

    $endTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $endTime;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off not running this script from a browser, but rather from the command line?

Comment: yeah I have also tried this and it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: For CLI the timeout should be hardcoded to `0`, i.e. never timeout. Are you getting an error message? Have you checked you logs? Perhaps you are running out of memory and not time.

Comment: yes sorry, its memory Im running out of, not time. I have no errors.

Comment: that *is* an error. And it is not "timing out" when it's running out of memory. You need to watch your memory usage in your code. Free up unused result sets etc. Use a debugger/profiler to see where you are going over the limit. Perhaps your `memory_limit` is just too small for your script ever to be able to complete.

Comment: How many rows are in the database? Have you considered processing it in chunks of ~ 1,000 records at a time (using LIMIT in your first SQL query)?

Comment: There's aprox 200 rows in the 1st database, so I dont think thats the problem.  If I try to run the script for individual customers, I only have an issue with the ones over 5,000 products, therefore its a problem within the generateFeed function. I have increased the memory_limit twice now. How do I "watch my memory usage" and "free up unused results sets" etc, I am new to working with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

I can see one thing that might help on your memory usage. If you move the fwrite() inside the foreach loop, you can free up $txt also inside the loop. So it would be something like:

```
foreach($products as $product){
  $txt =   
  $prod_name . $datafeed_separator . 
  $prod_brand . $datafeed_separator . 
  $prod_desc . $datafeed_separator .
  $prod_price . $datafeed_separator . "\n";  

  fwrite($fh, $txt);
}
```

This will prevent $txt growing large if you have many products.

Comment: there should only be 1000 products added to $txt at a time and then it would be written to the file so I didnt think this would cause a memory issue and why would it only become an issue after 5,000 products?